# What's the difference between "<-chan" and "chan" as a function return type?

Tags: go, channel

Golang newbie here.

Is there a functional difference between

```
func randomNumberGenerator() <-chan int {
```

and

```
func randomNumberGenerator() chan int {
```

I've tried using both and they seem to work fine for me.

I've seen the former used by Rob Pike (one of Go creators) in his Go Concurrency Patterns talk at Google IO 2012. I've also seen it used in Go's official website. Why add 2 extra characters ("<-") when you can omit it? I've tried looking for the difference on the web, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Both will work indeed. But one will be more constraining. The form with the arrow pointing away from the `chan` keyword means that the returned channel will only be able to be pulled from by client code. No pushing allowed : the pushing will be done by the random number generator function. Conversely, there's a third form with the arrow pointing towards `chan`, that makes said channel write-only to clients.

```
chan   // read-write
<-chan // read only
chan<- // write only
```

These added constraints can improve the expression of intent and tighten the type system : attempts to force stuff into a read-only channel will leave you with a compilation error, and so will attempts to read from a write-only channel. These constraints can be expressed in the return type, but they can also be part of the parameter signature. Like in :

```
func log(<-chan string) { ...
```

There you can know, just by the signature, that the `log` function will consume data from the channel, and not send any to it.

Comment: Thanks. `func log(<-chan string)` Should not there be a parameter name that I can use in the function like `func log(cs <- chan string)`?

Comment: Oh, I see you comment two years and a half late, sorry ! Yes of course. I've written a function type signature, not fully usable function declaration.

Answer (score 16):

This is an example of a [receive-only channel](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types).

> The optional `<-` operator specifies the channel direction, send or receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bidirectional. A channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by conversion or assignment.

It's useful to tell the users of your API that they should *only* receive from that channel and *never* send, otherwise bad things happen. It is considered a good practice to specify the direction of your channels in public APIs. See also: [Principles of designing Go APIs with channels](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2acr79/principles_of_designing_go_apis_with_channels/).

Comment: It's not only that "users should never send otherwise bad things happen". AFAIK, trying to send will just make the compiler bluntly angry at you.